# XML parser java skip dtd validation

Tags: java, xml-parsing, dtd

I want to skip DTD validation as I don't have a internet connection.Is it possible to implement that in java.

My code is:

```
  file = new File(filepath);  

            // Create instance of DocumentBuilderFactory  
            factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  

            // Get the DocumentBuilder  
            docBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  

            // Using existing XML Document  

            doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
```

My error is this and I know the reason for this error.

```
a.net.UnknownHostException: www.jboss.org  
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)  
       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(UnknownSource)  
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)  
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One outrageous hack would be to write a custom [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) extension which just removes the DTD reference before the parser sees it.